# What is the best way to validate data in Django REST framework?

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

I have tried validating incoming data in my serializer with custom validation logic.
is there any standard I should follow when I am doing this?

*And is it a good idea to write custom validation in my serailizers?
or, should I write them elsewhere and import the logic?
if not what would be the best way to implement it*

Here is an example of my implementation

**Serializer**

```
class PlaylistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Playlist
        fields = ["id", "name", "is_public", "playlist_image"]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "id": {"read_only": True},
        }
    
    def validate_playlist_image(self, obj):
        validate_picture(obj) # custom validator
        return obj
```

**Validator**

```
MAX_PICTURE_SIZE = 3 * 1024 * 1024  # value in bytes, max 3Mb


def validate_picture(picture):
    if picture.size > MAX_PICTURE_SIZE:
        raise ValidationError("Picture size can not be greater than 3Mb")
```

**Any suggestion is appreciated**

Comment: yes, you can override validate method

Comment: See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/ for more information on validators and custom validation

Answer (score 1):

you can apply it in two way

-from serializer:

```
    class BillingRecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       def validate(self, attrs):
       # Apply custom validation either here, or in the view.

    class Meta:
          fields = ['client', 'date', 'amount']
          validators = []  # Remove a default "unique together" constraint.
```

-from Views:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    serializer = YourSerializer(data=request.data)
    data = serializer.validated_data
    data['field_name'] # you can access field in this way and use it in any condation you want
```

good luck